# ordering a "window" of a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I'm new to R and this is my first question (apologies if the question is posed wrongly).

I would like to change the order of the rows accordingly to the values by the columns of a "window" inside a multidimensional array.

Here's a simplified example:

```
x1<-matrix(c(1,3,2,4), 2)
x1
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

x2<-matrix(c(7,5,8,6),2)
x2
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    8
[2,]    5    6


x3<-array(c(x1,x2), dim = c(2,2,2))
```

I would then like to re-arrange the first "window" of the array so that it will be like x4:

```
x4<-x1[order(x1[,1], decreasing = TRUE),]
x4
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    1    2
```

How can I do that inside the array? 
Plus, will the change affect also all the other "windows" in the array? 
So that, in the end, I will end up with an array like this:

```
x3[,,1]

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    1    2


x3[,,2]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]    7    8
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reorder the rows (1st dimension) of the array; It is similar to how you will reorder the rows of a matrix except that it is 3d so you need to specify three indices:

```
x3[order(x3[,2,1], decreasing = T),,]

#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    4
#[2,]    1    2

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    6
#[2,]    7    8
```

Comment: Thanks! However I forgot to specify that the rows should be ordered on a column basis; ie (continuing with the example); I would like to re-arrange the first window of the array like that : `apply(x1,2,decreasing = T,sort)` . But if I try to do like that: `apply(x3[,,1],2,sort, decreasing =T)` I end up with just the first window.

Comment: So you want all columns in descending order? That's not what you are showing with your desired output.

Comment: No, I just want to change the columns in descending order of ONLY 1 window. (in the example, the first 1; named x1). But I want to do it inside the array; in a such way that also the other windows should change accordingly (or not?). In the example I should have put the values of x2 as: (by col) A,B; C,D. Then, after ordering the columns of ONLY the first window of the array in ascending order: (by col) 3,1; 4,2 will, (automatically) the second window of the array change to: (by col) B,A; C,D ? (This is what I meant by: "Plus [...] array?"). I am sorry if I have not been clear.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean. Or guess here, if you mean whether it's possible to make changes in *x1* and then the everything automatically happens in *x3*, then it's no. *x3* has already copied all the data over and it's independent of *x1*.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1. can I change just one window of a multidimensional array? (and if yes, how). 2. will such a change affect all the other windows of the array? by windows I mean the matrices that compose the array. I am sorry, again, if it is not clear. (if it might help I'm seeing the array as a box:the rectangle dim correspond to the dimension of the windows, the volume of the box depends on the number of windows; correct me if i'm wrong. i'm rather new to R.)

Comment: You can change only one window by assigning the new array the corresponding window. `x3[,,1] <- apply(x3[,,1], 2, sort, decreasing=T)` for instance changes the first window only. This have no effect on other windows of the array.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I didn't get; I thought that elements in different matrices of an array were linked.